# Bootstrap 3 and Chrome v70

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am having an issue with an Angular 1 legacy application that broke after the Chrome update to version 70. I'm currently after 24 hours of debugging, and there is no light at the end of the tunnel. I checked the Chrome changelog and the depreciation section, and I did not find anything that would relate to me.

It looks like it's the `position: relative` in the `col-*-*` class, when I remove that, everything works but I can't point it to a logical reason.

Does anyone know of something else related to this that was affected by the chrome update?

P.S. I am not posting code because we are not talking about a single instance, it a full application...

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully debugged the issue in my application. After upgrading to Chrome 70, I noticed that on MDPI screens certain dropdowns and lists where multiple elements had ***position: relative;*** and ***overflow: hidden;*** would vanish.

What appeared to be happening was a z-indexing issue where my lists would become hidden behind dropdowns and other container elements. The solution was to apply a z-index to the container with overflow: hidden; on to the disappearing elements and that resolved it.

Hope the sheds some light on your situation.

Comment: What is this overflow-y: auto; on the bootstrap .modal this is causing all my issues.